# How to send generic data to angular popover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover, that triggers on textbox focus. I have to pass a `testvar`, defined as an attribute in the parent element (here a textbox), to the popover template. Here is the code:

> page_template.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Choose Start Date" 
       ng-model="data.filters.startdate" 
       popover-placement="bottom" 
       uib-popover-template="calendar_popover.html"
       popover-trigger="click" testvar="something"/>
```

> calendar_popover.html

```
<div>
    {{testvar}}
    <div>
        <calendar selected="testvar" highlight="selected"
                  select-callback="doSomething()"></calendar>
    </div>
</div>
```

The use case is that I have to show different dates on different popover, while using the same popover template. Like:

```
<input ... chosenDate="date1"/>
<input ... chosenDate="date2"/>
```

Then showing it on multiple popovers on the page, using generic code:

```
<calendar selected="chosenDate" highlight="selected" ...></calendar>
```

**EDIT**

This is the calendar directive:

```
.directive("calendar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/www/views/common/calendar.html",
        scope: {
            selected: "=selected",
            events: "=ngModel",
            selectCallback: '&',
            bindingFoo: "=",
        },
        link: function (scope, elements, attr) {
            ...
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: So you want to show `data.filters.startdate` in popover or what variable?

Comment: variable name would be `chosenDate` in popover.

Comment: Are trying to bind your own datepicker or something? Then just create custom directive that uses popover.

Comment: Yes, I have a custom directive called `calendar`. It shows a selected date on calendar that is passed to `selected` attribute.

Comment: I mean create directive that wraps both popover and calendar.